# AppClip not sending full invocation url to released application

Tags: swift, apple-appclips

Why is my AppClip receiving only the host (without path and query params) from messages but works when opening from Safari?

Did create an AppClip for an iOS app and was working fine in the development step (did always open and add the url sent with _XCAppClipURL in the scheme). Testing also worked in TestFlight with the invocation url set for AppClip.

When I update the app, on AppStore it does not work there (only getting the host as the invocation, no path or query parameters)

When opening from Safari AppClip everything works as expected but from messages it does not.

I'm using this url https://ethereum-address-tracker.com/address?address=0xC65F56eD1B59D21305DF058dde242968a752cb3A
and this is the association file on server. https://ethereum-address-tracker.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Any ideas?
Thanks